# Is it possible for dealloc to be called on an object whose retain count is NOT zero?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I'll keep this short and obvious: I have an object whose dealloc method is being called. I also have an NSTimer being called every 3 seconds to log to console the current retain count of said object.

Just to be clear: **I know that NSTimer will retain the object. The situation still does not add up even when considering this.**

Anyhow - at the time this timer fires, the retain count of the object is being logged as 3. This confuses me for 2 reasons:

1. Why is dealloc being called if the object's retain count is not ever reaching 0?
2. Since dealloc is getting called, shouldn't, at the very least, the retain count be 1 since the NSTimer instance is holding onto it?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(logRetainCount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

^ set in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)logRetainCount
{
    NSLog(@"own retain count: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)self));
}
```

^ method that logs retain count

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"view controller deallocated");
}
```

^ dealloc method implemented in the VC that is supposed to be deallocated

And the console output:

> own retain count: 5
>
> view controller deallocated
>
> own retain count: 3

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123528/discussion-on-question-by-tony-friz-is-it-possible-for-dealloc-to-be-called-on-a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask:

> Is it possible for `dealloc` to be called on an object whose retain count is NOT zero?

Since you're using ARC, we don't use "retain count" in that context anymore. But in answer to your question, no, an object cannot be deallocated while there are strong references. And when you call `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`, if that's a repeating timer, it will maintain a strong reference to the `target`, preventing the target from getting deallocated (at least until the timer's `invalidate` is called).

Consider:

```
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(logRetainCount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)logRetainCount {
    NSLog(@"own retain count: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)self));
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"view controller deallocated");
}

@end
```

When I push to this view controller, I see the following on the console:

```
2016-09-15 15:50:10.279 MyApp[7777:159811] own retain count: 3
2016-09-15 15:50:13.340 MyApp[7777:159811] own retain count: 3
```

And when I pop that view controller off, I see:

```
2016-09-15 15:50:16.338 MyApp[7777:159811] own retain count: 2
2016-09-15 15:50:19.270 MyApp[7777:159811] own retain count: 2
```

Note, we do *not* see "view controller deallocated" appear in the console.

When I click on Xcode 8's "Debug Memory Graph" button, we can see that the timer is still keeping a strong reference to it:

[image: timer]

You ask:

> 1. Why is `dealloc` being called if the object's retain count is not ever reaching 0?

It can't be. So, we must have multiple instances of the view controller involved here, one that has the repeating timer that isn't deallocated, and one without the timer, that is deallocated when its last strong reference is resolved. But whatever object is the `target` of the timer will still have a strong reference to it until the timer is invalidated, and it will not be deallocated until the timer has its `invalidate` called.

> 2. Since `dealloc` is getting called, shouldn't, at the very least, the retain count be 1 since the `NSTimer` instance is holding onto it?

No, while the repeating timer is firing, its target *cannot* be deallocated. We must be talking about multiple instances of the view controller (or, unlike the example above, the `target` of the timer wasn't the view controller).

There are lots of ways to accidentally introduce additional instances of a view controller. For a random example (one that I've seen here on Stack Overflow more than once), consider that you did a segue between two view controllers, and had a `prepareForSegue` that did something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    secondViewController.property = @"foo";
}
```

This is incorrect, because in addition to the view controller that the segue instantiated (the `segue.destinationViewController`), the above `prepareForSegue` will create another instance. The one created in `prepareForSegue` will be deallocated as soon as it falls out of scope, but the one created by the segue will not be deallocated because of the repeating timer that is created in `viewDidLoad`.

I'm not suggesting that this is what you did, but it illustrates one possible way to get the behavior you describe.

But, in short, no, in ARC, an object that still has any strong references will not be deallocated. Only when the last remaining strong reference is removed will it be deallocated. The code in your question cannot, alone, produce the behavior you describe. You must be dealing with some additional instance of the view controller or something curious like that. I might suggest you create a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem you describe because the code in your question does not. There's something else going on.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your effort. I really do greatly appreciate it. Second, you are correct: there are multiple instances of this view controller being allocated. And, fewer retain counts are being logged to the console than there are instances of this particular view controller. I do not know why I did not think of this but I feel silly for not being to come to this conclusion myself. I will try to confirm this and get to the bottom of it. And I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I am allowed.